# How to cut the center of a polar grid in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I cut out the center of a polar grid in Illustrator?

I created this grid with the outer circle removed:

[image: polar grid]

I'd like to cut out a circle in the center:

[image: polar grid with circle]

So that only the outer radial lines are left, like the units on a clock.

Pathfinder "Minus Front" doesn't won't work since the grid is not a single shape.

(I use Illustrator CS6.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select all and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Mac or
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Win to activate the **Shape Builder**
  Tool
- Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> click all the path inside the circle

[image: circle]

Comment: Thank you! I see it's Shift+M on the Mac.